# Go to another page in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I started my ionic project, but my main problem is going to another page.  I couldn't do this process.  I need some basic examples or basic tutorials.  Thank your already for your answers.

Comment: could you make your question more specific?

Comment: Seriously ... [it took me about 15secs to find this page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/). I do not want to downvote you because you are new but here you show your code that is giving you trouble and the community tries to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, declare '$state' like this

```
.controller('YourControllerName', function($state, ...
```

To navigate to different UI, use $state.go like this

```
$state.go('tab.main');
```

P.S: U will have to follow your app.js naming convention for the navigation. (for mine would be tab.main) :

```
//Sample app.js 
.state('tab.main', {
    url: '/main',
    views: {
        'tab-main': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```